# Editing grouped Boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been using ggplot2 to create a simple grouped boxplot by:

```
ggplot(data=all_data, aes(x=Season,y=`Depth (m)`,fill=site)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  xlab(NULL)
```

Which makes this

[image]

But there are several things I'd like to edit. First is the order of the boxes, I'd like to keep 'dry' on the left and 'wet' on the right but I want to reverse the site order so that 'Upstream' is on the left and 'downstream' is on the right within each group. Also, I tried to add error bar width and shapes on the mean values but when I use something like:

```
ggplot(data=all_data, aes(x=Season,y=`Depth (m)`,fill=site)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar',width=0.1) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point",shape=88,size=3) +
  xlab(NULL)
```

It produces this

[image]

I'd appreciate any help editing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rearrange the Upstream / Downstream categories, convert `site` to a factor with the appropriate levels. To have your errorbars and points line up with your boxplots, you need to ensure that you include `position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)` to their layers, otherwise they will fall between the boxplots.

So your code would look something like this:

```r
ggplot(data=all_data, aes(x = Season, y = `Depth (m)`, 
                          fill = factor(site, c('Upstream', 'Downstream')))) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.1,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 88, size = 3,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  labs(x = NULL, fill = 'Site')
```

[image]

---

**Data Used**

There was no data supplied by the OP, so I have made a data set with similar characteristics using this code:

```r
set.seed(1)

all_data <- data.frame(Season = rep(c('Dry', 'Wet'), each = 200),
                       `Depth (m)` = c(rnorm(100, 1.5, 0.5),
                                       rnorm(100, 1.75, 0.25),
                                       rnorm(100, 1.6, 0.3),
                                       rnorm(100, 1.9, 0.5)),
                       site = rep(rep(c('Downstream', 'Upstream'), 2), each = 100),
                       check.names = FALSE)
```

Running the OP's plot code on this data produces:

```r
ggplot(data = all_data, aes(x=Season,y=`Depth (m)`,fill=site)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  xlab(NULL)
```

[image]